# Summing up balances on forms for each record

Tags: ms-access-2016

This should be a simple answer, but i cant seem to find it anywhere for some reason.

I have an access form which allows me to enter data, including all stock details.  I have a field called stockin and a field called stockout for stock.  The user simply types in how many stocks go in or out.  Other fields identify the productName etc.  I wanted to put in another value (which i did with an unbound textbox) which sums the products that are currently in stock so that we know whether or not there is product in stock when the stockout field is filled out, or how much stock to fill out.  I thought i could do this by simply putting  a formula such as
=DSum("StockOut","[StockLevelsQuery]","[StockID] = " & [StockID])
in the DefaultValue section under the data tab.
The problem is that this DSum uses the same StockID for every single record, which seems to be the Stock ID for the first record.  Is there a way to make access circulate through the individual records or a better way to go about this.  I have tried assigning VBA code to onclicks and others but nothing seems to work.